# Java Program testing for a strictly increasing array after removing at most one element

Tags: java, arrays

Given a sequence of integers as an array, determine whether it is possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more than one element from the array.

For sequence = [1, 3, 2, 1], the output should be
almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = false;
There is no one element in this array that can be removed in order to get a strictly increasing sequence.

For sequence = [1, 3, 2], the output should be
almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = true.
You can remove 3 from the array to get the strictly increasing sequence [1, 2]. Alternately, you can remove 2 to get the strictly increasing sequence [1, 3].

The code which I've written for the above is given bellow , but it's not satisfying for sequence [1,2,3,4,3,6]
Actual output = false
expected output = true

```
boolean almostIncreasingSequence(int[] sequence) {
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE, count = 0;
        boolean flag = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < sequence.length-1 ; j++){
              if ( max >= sequence [j] || sequence[j]>=sequence[j+1]){
                 count++;
              }
              else
                 max = sequence[j];
              if ( count > 1){
                 flag = false;
                 break;
              }
        }        
        return flag; 
}
```

[time limit] : 3000ms (java)
[input] : array.integer sequence

Guaranteed constraints:
2 ≤ sequence.length ≤ 105,
-105 ≤ sequence[i] ≤ 105.

[output] : boolean

Return true if it is possible to remove one element from the array in order to get a strictly increasing sequence, otherwise return false.

Comment: Which answer did you expect and which answer did you get? Try to run with a debugger and check where the flow deviates from your expectations.

Comment: I'm expecting true value for that sequence but i'm getting false.

Comment: Now you need to find out why there is a count of 2. When is count incremented the first time? When the second time? Are these really different problems or are you counting one problem twice?

Comment: The problem is when j reach to value 4. I'm not finding the logic to solve it . If i correct for the sequence [1,2,3,4,3,6] then test case for  [1,2,1,2] is not satisfying .

Comment: The idea with `max` was quite good. You just have to make sure to check the full array.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the errors that can be fixed by just removing stuff from the original program:

```
boolean almostIncreasingSequence(int[] sequence) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE, count = 0;
    boolean flag = true;
    for (int j = 0; j < sequence.length; j++){
          if ( max >= sequence[j]){
             count++;
          }
          max = sequence[j];
          if ( count > 1){
             flag = false;
             break;
          }
    }        
    return flag; 
}
```

The main problem of the original version was, that the same out-of-order place was found two times. Just removing one of the checks, and at the same time adding one loop iteration solves this.

Comment: @NenadDordevic Oops, you are right. There was one more thing to delete from the original program. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This program goes through elements of array comparing if current is bigger or equal to next. If so it compares elements around current because it may be removed. And it compares elements around next because it may be removed. If deleting current or next doesn't make increasing array return false.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean almostIncreasingSequence = almostIncreasingSequence(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 99, 4, 3 });
    System.out.println(almostIncreasingSequence);
}

static boolean almostIncreasingSequence(int[] sequence) {
    int removeCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length - 1; i++) {
        int current = sequence[i];
        int next = sequence[i + 1];

        if (current >= next) {
            removeCount++;
            // Try to remove current. Skip removed element(current). Check
            // if previous is less than next element around current
            // if i is 0 there is no previous element
            // if removeCurrent is true it is possible to remove it and
            // arrays stays increasing
            boolean removeCurrent = i == 0 || sequence[i - 1] < next;
            // if removeNext is true it is possible to remove it and arrays
            // stays increasing
            boolean removeNext = i + 1 == sequence.length - 1 || current < sequence[i + 2];

            if (!removeCurrent && !removeNext)
                // if current is removed and array isn't increasing and if
                // next is removed and array is not increasing,
                // increment removeCount to return false
                removeCount++;
        }
        if (removeCount > 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

it meets all given test cases.

Comment: In this case you have to check if any of previous elements are not bigger t

Comment: Its not satifying for all test cases .
for example [1,2,1,2] expected is false

Comment: Thanks , it working for the above test cases. But its not satisfying for all.

Comment: sequence: [10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Output: false
Expected Output: true

sequence: [1, 2, 3, 4, 99, 5, 6]
Output: false
Expected Output: true


sequence: [123, -17, -5, 1, 2, 3, 12, 43, 45]
Output: false
Expected Output: true

Comment: I modified program and it gives expected results for provided sequences

Answer (score 0):

Based on your method, I would suggest you to do the following modification in your for loop:

for (......):

```
if s[i] >= s[i+1] count++
else if max >= s[i] count++
else max = s[i]
```

After finished for loop:
if count > 1 return false
else return true

Comment: Apart from all the syntax errors, this would still give false on [1,2,3,4,3,6].

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I didn't consider it carefully ( the code is just pseudo code )

Answer (score 0):

Using a simplistic brute force approach, create a method that returns an array with one of the elements missing, then check that array to see if it is increasing. A Loop around all of this should work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  if (IncreasingSequence(new int[] {1,2,3,4,3,6}))
    System.out.println("By removing one element the array is increasing");
  else
    System.out.println("By removing one element the array is Not increasing");
}

private static boolean IncreasingSequence(int[] sequence) {
  int[] nextArray;
  for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
      nextArray = MinusOneElement(sequence, i);
      if (CheckSequenceIncreasing(nextArray)) 
         return true;
    } 
  return false;
}

private static boolean CheckSequenceIncreasing(int[] sequence) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length - 1; i++) {
       if (sequence[i] >= sequence[i + 1]) {
           return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

private static int[] MinusOneElement(int[] sequence, int elementToRemove) {
   int[] newArray = new int[sequence.length - 1];
   int index = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
        if (i != elementToRemove) {
            newArray[index] = sequence[i];
            index++;
        }
   }
   return newArray;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your code is working for all the testcases.
But its increasing the time limit assign to me i.e 3000ms.
Is there any optimized way?

Comment: Sorry that is the best I can come up with right now. I will check it again tomorrow. If you do not create a new array with one less element (which I am guessing is the slow down), instead loop through the original array then you will have to do some special juggling inside the loop to ignore that element since it will obviously be at least `i` in one iteration and possibly `i + 1` in another iteration.

Answer (score 0):

For kotlin Programmers

```
fun almostIncreasingSequence(sequence: MutableList<Int>): Boolean 

{

var removeCount = 0;

var i = 0;

while  ( i < sequence.size - 1) {

var current = sequence[i];

var next = sequence[i + 1];

if (current >= next) {

removeCount++;

var removeCurrent : Boolean= i == 0 || sequence[i - 1] < next;

var removeNext : Boolean = i + 1 == sequence.size - 1 || current < sequence[i + 2];

if (!removeCurrent && !removeNext)

    removeCount++;

      }

      if (removeCount > 1) {

                    return false;

        }

      i++

    }

    return true;  

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution in kotlin:

```
fun solution(sequence: MutableList<Int>): Boolean {
     val newList = sequence.toSet().toList()

    if (sequence.size - newList.size > 1)
        return false
        
    if (newList == newList.sorted())
        return true
        
    val filterPairs = sequence.zipWithNext().filter { it.first >= it.second }

    if (filterPairs.size > 1)
        return false

    sequence.remove(filterPairs[0].first)
    
    if (sequence == sequence.toSet().toList() && sequence == sequence.sorted())
        return true
                
    return false
}
```